# Windows 7 taskbar tasks without a window in .Net

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, task

I'm trying to create an application for windows 7 that has taskbar tasks that are available even if there is no window like Media Player has.

I'm using the Windows API Code Pack and I've been able to add custom tasks but they are only available after a window is created and as soon as the window closes the tasks are removed.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the window transparent? You can also have it minimized if it is ok.

Comment: Then remove it from ALT + TAB as well (?)